# How can I replace all instances of a character between the Nth and Kth instance of that character?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I am working with a large number of CSV files, and in one of the columns, the field itself contains commas. Unfortunately, this column hasn't been enclosed in quotes, so it's causing an issue with loading the CSV files into external applications.

My CSV files look like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, co,,,l4, col5, col6
col1, col2, col3, co,,,,,l4, col5, col6
col1, col2, col3, co,,l4, col5, col6
```

I need to remove all the commas in this particular column, but I'm unsure of how to go about doing it. Unfortunately, rewriting the files with the problematic column properly enclosed in quotes isn't an option.

These problematic commas always occur *between* the third and second-last commas, but I don't have enough bash know-how to write a script that removes them.

Input file:

```
col1, col2, col3, co,,,l4, col5, col6
col1, col2, col3, co,,,,,l4, col5, col6
col1, col2, col3, co,,l4, col5, col6
```

Expected output:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the following suggestion:

```
awk '{ match($0,/^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,],/); p1=RLENGTH+1
       match($0,/,[^,]*,[^,]*$/);    ; p2=RSTART
       s=substr($0,p1,p2-p1); gsub(/,/,"",s)
       print substr($0,1,p1-1) s substr($0,p2)
     }' file.csv
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     { s=""; for(i=4;i<NF-1;++i) s=s $i }
     { print $1,$2,$3,s,$(NF-1),$NF }' file.csv
```

These solutions assume that no `,` appear in col1,col2,col3,col5 and col6.

If you have a comma in the other columns, but those columns are properly quoted according to the CSV-standard, then you can use a similar method based on [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

```
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' 'BEGIN{OFS=","}
     { s=""; for(i=4;i<NF-1;++i) s=s $i }
     { print $1,$2,$3,s,$(NF-1),$NF }' file.csv
```

---

More generically, to answer the title question:

> How can I replace all instances of a character between the Nth and Kth last instance of that character?

Assume `c` is the character:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="c"; n=3; k=}
     { s=""; for(i=1; i <= n   ;++i) s = $i OFS 
             for(   ; i <= NF-k;++i) s=s $i 
             for(   ; i <= NF  ;++i) s = OFS $i }
     { print s }' file.csv
```

Comment: Ah, so it turns out that some `,` do actually appear in the other columns, and they need to remain. Can these solutions be easily adapted so that only column 4 is affected? thanks

Comment: @isaaclangley if there are <commas> in the other columns, then the answer is no, unless that amount of commas is always the same in every line.

Comment: @isaaclangley are the other commas between double-quotes?

Comment: @isaaclangley I have added a solution that might solve it assuming that the other commas are quoted.

Comment: Alas no, the commas in the other columns are not quoted, and there are variable numbers of them per line.

Comment: So if the commas are not quoted, how can you identify column 4 from column 5?

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY just want to remove the commas in that field then with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
awk 'match($0,/(([^,]*,){3})(.*)((,[^,]*){2})/,a){gsub(/,/,"",a[3]); $0=a[1] a[3] a[4]} 1' file
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
```

but otherwise I'd just wrap the troublesome field in double quotes and then treat it like any other CSV (e.g. see [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001)):

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(([^,]*,){3})(.*)((,[^,]*){2})/,a){$0=a[1] "\"" a[3] "\"" a[4]} 1' file
col1, col2, col3," co,,,l4", col5, col6
col1, col2, col3," co,,,,,l4", col5, col6
col1, col2, col3," co,,l4", col5, col6

$ awk '
    BEGIN { FPAT="[^,]*|\"[^\"]+\"" }
    match($0,/(([^,]*,){3})(.*)((,[^,]*){2})/,a) { $0=a[1] "\"" a[3] "\"" a[4] }
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NR, NF, i, $i }
' file
1 6 1 col1
1 6 2  col2
1 6 3  col3
1 6 4 " co,,,l4"
1 6 5  col5
1 6 6  col6
2 6 1 col1
2 6 2  col2
2 6 3  col3
2 6 4 " co,,,,,l4"
2 6 5  col5
2 6 6  col6
3 6 1 col1
3 6 2  col2
3 6 3  col3
3 6 4 " co,,l4"
3 6 5  col5
3 6 6  col6
```

or just to do the quoting part with sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(([^,]*,){3})(.*)((,[^,]*){2})/\1"\3"\4/' file
col1, col2, col3," co,,,l4", col5, col6
col1, col2, col3," co,,,,,l4", col5, col6
col1, col2, col3," co,,l4", col5, col6
```

The above requires GNU or BSD/OSX sed for `-E`. With any POSIX sed it'd be:

```
$ sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\(.*\)\(\(,[^,]*\)\{2\}\)/\1"\3"\4/' file
col1, col2, col3," co,,,l4", col5, col6
col1, col2, col3," co,,,,,l4", col5, col6
col1, col2, col3," co,,l4", col5, col6
```